# Cannot add foreign key constraint for mysql

Tags: mysql, create-table

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(enum  VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
Last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Salary decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_pkey PRIMARY KEY(enum)); 

CREATE TABLE LECTURER
(enum VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
lecturerNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ranK VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
bioDate VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_enum primary key(enum),
CONSTRAINT LECTURER_fkey FOREIGN KEY (enum) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(enum),
CONSTRAINT lect_rank CHECK(rank in('L1'or'L2'or'L3')));

  CREATE TABLE MANAGER
 (enum VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 role VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_enum primary key(enum),
CONSTRAINT MANAGER_fkey FOREIGN KEY(enum) 
    REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(enum)      ON       DELETE CASCADE);

  CREATE TABLE SUBJECT
(subjectCode CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 SubjectName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 credit decimal(3,3) NOT NULL,
 taughtBy char(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT SUBJECT_PK PRIMARY KEY(subjectCode),
 CONSTRAINT SUBJECT_fkey FOREIGN KEY(taughtBy) 
   REFERENCES        LECTURER(lecturerNum) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT CREDIT_CHECK CHECK(credit >0));
```

I did not find any error on my create table, why when I run it at the subject table it says:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Why..... can anyone help me with it?

Comment: `enum` is a reserve keyword, use some other word instead

Answer (score 1):

LECTURER.lecturerNum does not have an index, which is required to be able to use it in a FK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE LECTURER
(enum VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
lecturerNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ranK VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
bioDate VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
KEY lecturerNum (lecturerNum),
CONSTRAINT pk_enum primary key(enum),
CONSTRAINT LECTURER_fkey FOREIGN KEY (enum) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(enum),
CONSTRAINT lect_rank CHECK(rank in('L1'or'L2'or'L3')));
```